# Как прервать нужный поток в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Разбираюсь с потоками, написал такой код:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse horsik = new Horse();
        Thread tr1 = new Thread(horsik, "Anna");
        tr1.start();
        horsik.horseStop();
    }
    public static class Horse implements  Runnable{

        public void horseStop(){
            String trName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(trName);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь из метода main, через статический метод написанный в классе - остановить поток, но не работает. Объясните пожалуйста почему?

Answer (score 1):

Для завершения потока нужно завести флаг, в методе horseStop этот флаг устанавливать, и выходить и из run  по этому флагу.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse horsik = new Horse();
        Thread tr1 = new Thread(horsik, "Anna");
        tr1.start();
        horsik.horseStop();
    }
    public static class Horse implements  Runnable{
        boolean stop = false;
        public void horseStop(){
            String trName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(trName);
            stop = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!stop){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем выдумывать велосипед? У потоков уже заложен механизм прерывания, надо только понять как им правильно пользоваться. Вот хорошая статья https://codepumpkin.com/interruptedexception-java-multithreading/

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что это называется не `усыпить`, а `прервать`.

Этот код не работает так как вы ожидаете потому, что метод `horseStop` вызывается в главном потоке (т.е. потоке который выполняет метод `main`). А остановить вы хотите другой поток, тот который выполняет метод `Horse.run`. Поэтому сигнал прерывания посылается не тому потоку, которому вы хотите его послать.

`Thread.currentThread()` возвращает текущий поток, из которого собственно происходит вызов этой функции. Вам же нужно вызывать `interrupt` на объекте `tr1`. Так как ссылка на объект `tr1` недоступна внутри `horseStop`, то придется унаследовать `Horse` от `Thread`:

```
class Horse extends Thread {
    public void horseStop(){
        String trName = this.getName();
        System.out.println(trName);
        this.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        }
    }
}
```

Только учтите, что правильно проверять на прерывание внутри run нужно так:

```
try {
    // делаем что-то 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // нас прервали   
}
```

Comment: Ни используя наследование от Thread, я лишаюсь возможности наследоваться от какого нибудь другого класса. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Если нужно прерывание делать именно изнутри `Horse`, то нужно обязательно иметь ссылку на поток. Это значит, что варианта только три: 1. наследование от `Thread` (т.е. доступ через `this`) 2. хранить ссылку на Thread в поле `Horse` 3. связь между `Horse` и `Thread` хранится во внешнем классе и `Horse` о нем знает и его использует, чтоб добраться до `Thread`

Comment: Можно вас на примере попросить? Как хранить ссылку на Thread, на примере моего кода? и как сделать связь между Horse и Thread?  Спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyApril см мой ответ

Comment: Как раз так проверять не получится, т. К. Нет ничего, что кидалово бы  `InterruptedException`. Проверять нужно именно флаг с помощью `isInterrupted() ` или статического `interrupted)) `, который к тому же сбрасывает флаг в исходное состояние, т. Е.  false

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже не люблю наследоваться от `Thread`, поэтому юзаю такой метод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Horse horsik = new Horse();
    horsik.horseStop();
}

public static class Horse implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    public Horse() {
        this.t = new Thread("Anna");
        this.t.start();
    }

    public void horseStop() {
        String trName = this.t.getName();
        System.out.println(trName);
        this.t.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        }
    }
}
```