# Как завершить остальные потоки после того, как завершились три первых?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть несколько объектов класса Horse которая экстендить Thread, и у него есть параметры как имя, скорость, дистанция которую нужно преодолеть. Задача такая - выявить первых трех победителей и вывести их имена и завершить остальные потоки.
Для меня многопоточность очень непонятная тема. Я никак не могу понять как завершить остальные потоки после того, как выявлены три победителя.
Вот метод run()

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println(name+" started the race");
    int counter = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp!=distance)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        temp+=speed;
        //System.out.println("Distance-"+temp);
        if(temp >= distance) break;
    }
    System.out.println(name+" finished the race");
}
```

И вот код в main()

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int distance = 5000;
    Horse h1 = new Horse("Cleveland",distance,15,0);
    Horse h2 = new Horse("Adobe",distance,25,0);
    Horse h3 = new Horse("Cinnamon",distance,17,0);
    Horse h4 = new Horse("Opie",distance,35,0);
    Horse h5 = new Horse("Fiona",distance,27,0);
    Horse h6 = new Horse("Russel",distance,50,0);


    ArrayList<Horse> horses = new ArrayList<Horse>(Arrays.asList(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6));
    for (int i =0;i<horses.size();i++)
    {
        horses.get(i).start();
    }
    int count =1;
    for (int i =0;i<horses.size();i++)
    {
        horses.get(i).join();
        if(!horses.get(i).isAlive()&&count<=3)
        {
            System.out.println(horses.get(i).getNameH()+" finished-"+count);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Да, я понимаю, что этот кусок кода не завершает поток, а лишь показывает последних кто финишировал. Никаких других идеи у меня нет.

```
int count =1;
    for (int i =0;i<horses.size();i++)
    {
        horses.get(i).join();
        if(!horses.get(i).isAlive()&&count<=3)
        {
            System.out.println(horses.get(i).getNameH()+" finished-"+count);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего к этому моменту все запущенные потоки уже будут остановлены, но не факт.

Comment: Да, они будут остановлены, но не моментально. В идеале остальные должны остановиться сразу же, после финиширования третьего потока.

Comment: Как кучно лошадепотоки пошли, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202420/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо в методе `run` отслеживать некоторую переменную, которая скажет, что следует завершить поток (будем отслеживать значение `finishedCount`, это атомарное представление `int`, которое предоставляет потокбезопасные методы). Также вам нужна структура, которая будет хранить лучших лошадей, для простосты сделаем обычный `ArrayList` - `winners`.

```
public class Main {
      public static AtomicInteger finishedCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
      public static List<Horse> winners = new ArrayList<Horse>();

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int distance = 5000;
        Horse h1 = new Horse("Cleveland", distance, 15, 0);
        Horse h2 = new Horse("Adobe", distance, 25, 0);
        Horse h3 = new Horse("Cinnamon", distance, 17, 0);
        Horse h4 = new Horse("Opie", distance, 35, 0);
        Horse h5 = new Horse("Fiona", distance, 27, 0);
        Horse h6 = new Horse("Russel", distance, 50, 0);
    
        ArrayList<Horse> horses = new ArrayList<Horse>(Arrays.asList(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6));
        for (int i = 0; i < horses.size(); i++) {
          horses.get(i).start();
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < horses.size(); i++) {
          horses.get(i).join(); // Дожидаемся завершения всех потоков
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          System.out.println(winners.get(i).getNameH() + " finished position: " + i);
        }
      }
}
```

Метод `run` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(name + " started the race");
    int counter = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp != distance) {

      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (finishedCount.get() >= 3) { // если есть 3 победителя, то завершаем исполнение потока
        System.out.println(name + " failed the race");
        return;
      }
      temp += speed;
      //System.out.println("Distance-"+temp);
      if (temp >= distance) break;
    }
    if (finishedCount.getAndIncrement() < 3) { //getAndIncrement() аналогично count = i++, только в потокобезопасном варианте, т.е. мы сначала считываем значение, а затем инкрементируем его
      winners.add(this); //Добавляем лошадь в победители, так как она в тройке лучших
    }
    System.out.println(name + " finished the race");
  }
```

P. S. решение не идеальное, предложены минимальные исправления для того, чтобы показать как в общем решать подобную проблему, понятное дело, что так или иначе многопоточность требует гораздо внимательнее относиться к потокобезопасности. Помимо `AtomicInteger` не помешало бы использовать и другие структуры из пакета `java.util.concurrent.*`, но я субъективно считаю, что это усложнит понимание решения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Все прекрасно работает